# Логика без использования редиректа

Tags: php, wordpress

Какие есть способы реализации открытия поста без использования редиректа?
Идея заключается в следующем: 
Категория -> Сабкатегория (если в сабкатегории всего один пост - открыть этот пост  при клике) -> Пост.

Вот мой код который работает с JS и делает переадресацию на нужную страницу как это было задуманно.

```html
<?php
} 
}elseif (count($posts) == 1) {
    $i=1;
    foreach($posts as $cpost)
    {
      $number = $pr_id = sprintf("%02d", $i);
      $sub_newlink = get_permalink($cpost->ID);
      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.location.href = '".$sub_newlink."';</script>";
      exit;
  }
?>
```

Как можно реализовать это только с помощью PHP и без переадресации? 
Что бы 1-ая сабкатегория унаследовала линк этого поста? Сейчас линк 2-сабкатегории выглядит так. Как его можно прикрутить к 1-ой?

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($cpost->ID) ?>" class="wk_link" title="<?php echo($cpost->post_title); ?>">
```

Сейчас мой код работает но это происходит следующим образом:
1. Сабкатегория имеет линк на след сабкатегорию и только потом с этой сабкатегории делает редирект на пост.

Реализация 2:

```
elseif (count($posts) == 1) {
$i=1;
print_r($posts[0]->ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Что бы 1-ая сабкатегория унаследовала линк этого поста?

Никак. Слаг в ВП - вещь уникальная.

Comment: Добавил в мой код "реализация 2". Сейчас работает правильно и отображается ID поста без редиректа. Но как можно получить полный контент поста?

Answer (score 0):

С помощь PHP редирект делается только в [HTTP-заголовке](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) 
Но чтобы он сработал нельзя перед его вызовом делать какой-либо вывод типа echo или print и прочее.

Другими словами: проверяйте сначала выражение, потом по необходимости делайте

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

И только потом делайте вывод тегов, скриптов и прочее.

Comment: Не зная ВП - не нужно давать такие советы. Тем более что это вообще не ответ на вопрос.